# SQL sum of two fields

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table with following fields

```
vchnrno credit debit amount
JV1      BA10   0     100 
JV1      BA11   0      10 
JV1       0     BC10   90
JV1       0     BC11   20
```

Usually sum of credit side= sum of debit side for every JV
here

1. credit = sum of BA10+ BA11 = 110
2. debit = sum of BC10 + BC 11 = 110

I want to find all JV's whose sum of debit - sum of credit >0

Comment: is there no possibility that the credits are > than debits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `SUM` + `CASE` might do the job. Here's how:

```
SQL> with test (vchnrno, credit, debit, amount) as
  2    (select 'JV1', 'BA10', '0'   , 100 from dual union all
  3     select 'JV1', 'BA11', '0'   ,  10 from dual union all
  4     select 'JV1', '0'   , 'BC10',  90 from dual union all
  5     select 'JV1', '0'   , 'BC11',  20 from dual union all
  6     --
  7     select 'xxx', 'XX20', '0'   ,  50 from dual union all
  8     select 'xxx', '0'   , 'xx30',  70 from dual
  9    )
 10  select vchnrno, sum_credit, sum_debit, sum_debit - sum_credit diff
 11  from (select vchnrno,
 12               sum(case when credit <> '0' then amount end) sum_credit,
 13               sum(case when debit  <> '0' then amount end) sum_debit
 14        from test
 15        group by vchnrno
 16       )
 17  where sum_debit - sum_credit > 0;

VCH SUM_CREDIT  SUM_DEBIT       DIFF
--- ---------- ---------- ----------
xxx         50         70         20

SQL>
```

I included `vchnrno = xxx` into sample data because `JV1` doesn't match criteria (`sum of debit = sum of credit`) so it wouldn't be returned anyway.